# Characteristic polynomial of unique matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Calculate the characteristic polynomial of $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_0 \\-1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & a_1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0 & a_2 \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -1 & a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

So we need to calculate the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_0 \\-1 & -\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 & a_1 \\ 0 & -1 & -\lambda & ... & 0 & a_2 \\ ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -1 & a_{n-1}-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$

I solved $det(\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda & a_0 \\ -1 & a_1-\lambda\end{bmatrix})=(-\lambda (a_1 - \lambda))+a_0=\lambda^2-a_1\lambda+a_0$.

This leads me to believe that the determinant I am trying to find is: $\lambda^n-a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+a_{n-2}\lambda^{n-2}-...+(-1)^na_0$, but I am struggling to prove this theory.

Comment: Looks like inducting on $n$ might be useful to determine the veracity of your hypothesis. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's a variant of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You've done the base case, so follow up with an induction.

Another hint:  It would be handy that the previous case appear as a minor in expansion by minors.

> For instance, \begin{align} &\det \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_0  \\  -1 & -\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 & a_1  \\   0 & -1 & -\lambda & ... & 0 & a_2  \\   ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...  \\   0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -\lambda & a_{n-2}  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -1 & a_{n-1}-\lambda \end{bmatrix}  \\  &=  (- \lambda) \det \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_1  \\  -1 & -\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 & a_2  \\   0 & -1 & -\lambda & ... & 0 & a_3 \\  ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...  \\   0 & 0 & 0 & ... & a_{n-3}  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -1 & a_{n-1}-\lambda  \end{bmatrix} -  (-1)\det \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_0  \\  -1 & -\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 & a_2  \\   0 & -1 & -\lambda & ... & 0 & a_3  \\   ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...  \\   0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -\lambda & a_{n-2}  \\  0 & 0 & 0 & ... & -1 & a_{n-1}-\lambda \end{bmatrix}  \text{.}  \end{align} The first determinant (the one multiplied by $-\lambda$ ) evaluates via your inductive hypothesis and the last determinant is easy by expanding along the first row (leaving $a_0$ times a determinant of an upper-triangular matrix containing only $-1$ s and $-\lambda$ s).